# detect when app has started from a file association launch

Tags: android, intentfilter

I've successfully added intent filters to my apps manifest to register for pdf file association.

When my app starts I need it to take different actions if it was started from a file association launch rather than starting from pressing the apps icon.

Is it possible to distinguish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can distinguish between the two, by the action set on the Intent of the main activity call:

```
String action = getIntent().getAction();
```

If the action is action.MAIN then the app was started by pressing the icon in the app drawer.
If its action.VIEW or whatever action you have set in the intent filter for the activity in Manifest.xml, then it was a file association launch.

Comment: thanks. 
Because I further need to take two different actions I was thinking about creating 2 intent filters. Is there a way in the app to identify which of the two intent filters was used to launch the app?

Comment: Perhaps checking the manifest intent filter android:label in the app. I that possible?

Comment: 2 intent filters with the same action?

Comment: If you give more info on what you are trying to achieve, I may be able to help.

Comment: The app extracts either images or text from pdfs. So two intent-filters, one for each action. How in app can I identify which intent-filter launched the app? Perhaps putextra or flag in manifest, not sure if possible?

Comment: if you have 2 different actions then you can use them to differentiate.

Comment: But how? Perhaps putextra or flag in manifest, not sure if possible?

Comment: try with <data android:mimeType="text/*" /> and <data android:mimeType="image/*" /> on each of the intent filters.